# How does $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}$ behave as $n$ tends to infinity?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}$ unbounded as n tends to infinity?  ($\sigma(n)$ is sum of proper divisors of $n$)

Answer (score 3):

Let $\sigma(n)$ be the sum of divisors function.

It is known that
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sigma(n)}{n\log\log n}=e^\gamma,$$
where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

From this it follows that your ratio is unbounded.  The "worst case" behaviour of $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}$, and hence of your ratio, is very accurately known.

Please see [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Approximate_growth_rate) for some detail and references.

**Remark:** But one could argue that $\ln\ln n$ is real-world bounded, and indeed quite small!

Comment: Also: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/28235/variants-of-gronwalls-theorem

Comment: and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/79927/which-n-maximize-gn-frac-sigmann-log-log-n

Comment: "log log log x goes to infinity with great dignity."
Dan Shanks (Math. Comp. 13 (1959), 272-284). Anonymous: "logloglog n has been proved to go to infinity, but has never been observed to do so."