# $lim(σ(n+1)/σ(n))$ as $n→∞$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Is the following limit bounded?

$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{σ(n+1)}{σ(n)}$

Where $σ(n)$ is sum divisor function.

Comment: @DietrichBurde tow case.

Comment: @DietrichBurde $σ(n)$

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687413/how-does-frac-sigmann-behave-as-n-tends-to-infinity?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde your mean: my question is unbounded?

Comment: I explored a little and found that there is a way to represent this function as a product of its prime factors. Since we know that two consecutive integers are coprime, there would be no visible cancelations in this limit, which leads me to believe it is unbounded. Refer to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#CITEREFHardyWright2008) for the formula that I am talking about. Note that I am only speculating and cannot say for sure at this point due my sleep-deprived state.

Comment: @Hersh please write your idea.

Comment: Asking if the limit is bounded implicitly imply the limit exists or it's infinite (and that's not the case). You probably want to ask if the **sequence** $\frac{\sigma(n+1)}{\sigma(n)}$ is bounded or if the $\limsup$ is finite.

Comment: @jjagmath I want know that this limit as tends to infinite?

Comment: @AmiraliFatehizadeh No, that limit does not tend to infinity. That's easy to see  because $\sigma(n) \ge n+1$ for $n \ge 2$ and equality holds only for prime numbers. So if $n+1$ is prime, your quotient will be a less than 1, except for $n=2$, where both involoved numbers are prime.

Comment: @Ingix Thanks. Now, is bounded?

Comment: What is bounded? There may be no limit. Please clarify the question in your post.

Comment: @DietrichBurde for example, limit on the my post tends to $a$ where $a$ is natural number.